# Compact Fourier multiplier?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let us take some continuous $m\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ and suppose $m(\xi)\to 0$ as $|\xi|\to \infty$. Let $T_m:L^2(\mathbb R^d)\to L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ be the associated Fourier multiplier operator, i.e. $\widehat{T_m f} = m \widehat{f}$. As we know in general these Fourier multipliers are NOT compact operators. The reason for this is that $\mathsf R(m)$ might contain some open set, and for compact operators we require the spectrum to have at most one accumulation point, namely zero.

Set $\mathcal X := [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]^d$. Now I am trying to find a way to make compact the restriction of $T_m$ to the subspace $L^2(\mathcal X) := \{ f \in L^2(\mathbb R^d) : \mathrm{supp}(f) \subseteq \mathcal X\}$. I have a few reasons to believe it might be compact on this subspace, but I feel like I am missing some crucial background knowledge. My reasons are the following:

1. We can represent any $f\in L^2(\mathcal X)$, for $x\in\mathcal X$ by

$$ f(x) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z^d} \hat{f}(k) e^{2\pi i x \cdot k}, $$

with $\hat{f}(k) = \int_{\mathcal X} f(x) e^{-2\pi i x\cdot k} \ dx$. Now for Fourier series (on the torus), compactness of Fourier multipliers is much easier: $T_m$ is compact whenever $m\to 0$.  This looks a lot like our assumption above. However, it is not immediately clear to me how we can use the assumption above.

2. If we had the additional assumption that $m \in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$, then we could take the IFT of $m$ to find that in fact $\mathcal F^{-1} m \in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$, so the operator $T_m$ would act on $L^2(\mathcal X)$ like a convolution with an $L^2(\mathcal X\times\mathcal X)$ function. This operator is then a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, since we are only convolving with functions with support on $\mathcal X$. Note however that this assumption is not necessary, as this approach only would require $\mathcal F^{-1} m \in L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb R^d)$, not $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$.
3. If instead we had the additional assumption that $m \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$, we could say $\mathcal F^{-1} m\in L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$, and we could again view $T_m$ on $L^2(\mathcal X)$ as a convolution with an $L^2(\mathcal X \times \mathcal X)$ kernel. Again this assumption is too strong, as we would in this case only need $\mathcal F^{-1}m\in L^\infty_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb R^d)$.

Now, looking at $[\mathcal F^{-1} m] 1_{\mathcal X}$ also does not give anything useful (as far as I can tell). If we take the FT of $[\mathcal F^{-1} m] 1_{\mathcal X}$, we end up with

$$ (m \star \widehat{1_{\mathcal X}})(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R^d} m(x)\prod_{j=1}^d \mathrm{sinc}(\xi_j - x_j) \ dx. $$

And these sinc integrals are terrible to deal with, because $\mathrm{sinc}$ is not $L^1$, there is almost no way to estimate these integrals without losing important information. I have tried searching on the internet and in the literature for ways to solve these integrals and the approach people use is... a Fourier transform to get the indicator function...

I really am at a loss here and feel like I am missing something. Surely someone must have tried something similar before?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It would be better to write down the explicit definition of $T_m$. Not everybody here is familiar with harmonic analysis. You would get more attention.

Comment: This is a good question, in any case. Is it the case that, if $m$ is compactly supported, then $T_m$ is compact on $\mathcal X$? I would say so. Then, you could argue by approximation; take a sequence $m_n$ of compactly supported multipliers which converges to $m$ uniformly. The resulting sequence of operators converges in the operator norm, and so compactness carries over to the limit.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Hi, thank you for your comment. I am indeed taking $T_m$ as a Fourier multiplier. I have clarified this in the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator is indeed compact on $\mathcal X$. To prove this, we need to use the $L^2$ version of the theorem of Ascoli and Arzelà, and while answering this question I found a nice little paper of Robert Pego with it;

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-095-02/S0002-9939-1985-0801333-9/S0002-9939-1985-0801333-9.pdf

---

Let us see the details. As in the question, let $m\colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb C$ be such that $m(\xi)\to 0$ as $\lvert \xi \rvert \to \infty$, and define
$$
T_m f = \mathcal F^{-1}( m \hat f),$$
where $\mathcal F$ and $\widehat{}$ denote the Fourier transform. We claim that this operator of $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ into itself is compact on
$$\mathcal X=\{f\in L^2\, :\, \text{supp}(f)\subset B_1\}.$$
(Here $B_1$ denotes the unit ball of $\mathbb R^d$, but any subspace of functions supported in some common bounded set will yield the same result).

To prove this, we consider a sequence $f_n\in \mathcal X$ such that $\lVert f_n\rVert_2\le 1$. As stated in the linked paper, to prove that $\{T_m f_n\}$ is a relatively compact subset of $L^2$ we need to check two conditions;

1. *Equiboundedness*. the norm $\lVert T_m f_n \rVert_2$ must be uniformly bounded;
2. *Equicontinuity*. $$\lim_{R\to \infty}\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}\int_{\lvert \xi\vert \ge R} \lvert \widehat{T_m f_n}(\xi)\rvert^2\,d\xi=0.$$

(There is also a third condition - *equivanishing* -, but it is automatically satisfied since all $f_n$ are supported in the same bounded set. **EDIT** This is true but it is not as trivial as I am putting it. See [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4675589/8157) for details on this important point).

Now, the first condition is obviously satisfied, since $T_m$ is bounded. The second is satisfied because of the assumption on $m$, since
$$\int_{\lvert \xi\vert \ge R} \lvert \widehat{T_m f_n}(\xi)\rvert^2\,d\xi = \int_{\lvert \xi\vert \ge R} \lvert m(\xi)\rvert^2 \lvert \hat f_n(\xi)\rvert^2\,d\xi\le \sup_{\lvert \xi \rvert \ge R} \lvert m(\xi)\rvert^2, $$
and the right-hand side tends to $0$. $\Box$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and the article you linked! I assume the $|\xi|\leq R$ in the integrals is supposed to be $|\xi| > R$. Also, I read your previous comment about approximating $m$ with compactly supported $m_n$. Is there a reason you chose not to prove it this way? Because to me it seems like a nice, and also simple way of proving $T_m$ is compact. Anyway, many thanks because this characterisation of compact subsets of $L^p(\mathbb R^d)$ from the article is surely going to come in handy later on.

Comment: OOh sorry sorry it is $\lvert \xi\rvert > R$ indeed. The idea is that you control high frequencies, which correspond to control the “derivative”, and this gives the “$L^2$ equicontinuity” required by Ascoli Arzelà. Assuming that $m$ is compactly supported makes the right-hand side of the last equation exactly 0, rather than just tending to 0 as $R\to \infty$. In the end it is not a real simplification, imho.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro sharp as usual :)

Comment: @JoãoRamos: thank you my friend! it is nice to see you here, I hope you are doing well.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but I don't immediately see why the equivanishing property is satisfied. Yes, the sequence $f_n$ has the same bounded support, but the sequence $T_m f_n$ might not, right?

Comment: @Hidde: Of course, but equivanishing is about $f_n$, not $T_mf_n$. It's been two years since this answer so I might be misremembering something.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I understand, I just recently found this post and think it is a very interesting question. The way I understand it, we should verify equivanishing for $T_mf_n$, since this is the sequence we want to be relatively compact. I'll have think about it as well. At least, since you proved equi-continuity, we have that $T_mf_n$ is relatively compact on bounded sets.

Comment: @Hidde: It can be that you are right, of course. This subscript $m$ is a bit confusing after two years. This $m$ is not a sequence index, it is a reminder that $T_m$ is a multiplier with symbol $m=m(\xi)$. The sequence is $(T_m f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and indeed you're right, it is $T_m f_n$ that should have a convergent subsequence. So it is $T_m f_n$ that should be equivanishing and it is not obvious that it is. Doesn't the same argument as for equicontinuity work for equivanishing too? Sorry to answer your question with another question!

Answer (score 2):

As discussed with @GiuseppeNegro in the comments, it seems that we agree that the equivanishing property for the sequence $(T_mf_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not follow immediately. However, it can be proven with similar methods.

First off, Theorem 1 in Robert Pego's article says that the equivanishing is equivalent to equicontinuity in Fourier space, that is \begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:1}\lim_{h \to 0}\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} ||\widehat{T_mf_n}-\widehat{T_mf_n}(\cdot+h)||_{2}=0.\end{equation} To verify this, we compute \begin{align*}\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} ||\widehat{T_mf_n}-\widehat{T_mf_n}(\cdot+h)||_{2} &= \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||m\widehat{f}_n - m(\cdot+h)\widehat{f}_n(\cdot+h)||_{2} \\
&\leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||m\widehat{f}_n - m\widehat{f}_n(\cdot+h)||_{2}+||m\widehat{f}_n(\cdot+h) - m(\cdot+h)\widehat{f}_n(\cdot+h)||_{2} \\
&\leq ||m||_{\infty} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||\widehat{f_n}-\widehat{f_n}(\cdot+h)||_{2} + \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||\widehat{f}_n||_{2}||m-m(\cdot+h)||_\infty.\end{align*} Now, since $(f_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ has fixed compact support, it satisfies the equivanishing property and thus, by Theorem 1 of Robert Pego, $\lim_{h \to 0}\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} ||\widehat{f_n}-\widehat{f_n}(\cdot+h)||_{2}=0$. Moreover, we have $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||\widehat{f}_n||_{2} =\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||f_n||_2 <\infty$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}||m-m(\cdot+h)||_\infty=0$ since $m$ is continuous and vanishing at infinity. Combining all of this, we find that (1) follows.

Comment: Right, this makes sense. In the end it is Plancherel that saves the day, since $\lVert \widehat{f}_n-\widehat{f}_n(\cdot + h)\rVert_2= C\lVert (1-e^{ixh})f_n\rVert_2$ and so the common boundedness of the supports of the $f_n$ kicks in. I *would like*
 to say that this is what I meant two years ago, but the actual truth is that I do not remember at all, and it may very well have been a massive oversight on my part. Thank you for fixing it!